# Express app.get static file with "." in filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.get('/images/:filename', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params.filename);
  const newUrl = `/static/images/${req.params.filename}`;
  req.url = newUrl;
  next();
});
```

Above code works fine if `filename` does not contain a special character `.`

For example `localhost/images/myImage.jpg` will print out `myImage.jpg`.

If `filename` contains a `.` such as `localhost/images/my.Image.jpg`, console will not print out anything. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: Added code below. I'm not sure what it does.

```
app.get(
    /^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico)$/,
    (req, res) => {
        res.status(404).end();
    }
);
```

Edit 2: My bad! Like someone's comment, I found the problem was actually from Service Worker. It was apparently messing with caching.

Could somebody explain what `^.+\.$` does in the second piece of code above? I'll mark the answer for that one instead.

Comment: That's not true. `:filename` param should work with both `myImage.jpg` and `my.Image.jpg`. Extra dot in parameter doesn't affect how it works. The problem isn't in the posted code and shouldn't affect `console.log` calls. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's express.js? If so, `:parms` is not the best candidate to pass complex values (e.g. something more complex that simple alphaliteral, ehm, params). You could try to pass it to [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) isntead of `params` and properly escape it client-side and unescape server-side

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this documentation:

[Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)